# Merging 2 branches in github

Tags: android, github, merge, branch

I have tried all sorts of solutions that Ive seen on this site. No score.
On github I have Project-Rachel and MM-mr2. I want to merge the branch from MM-mr2 into Project-Rachel. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is all involving Android kernel source.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout as the branch you want to merge in, in your case Project-Rachel. Click `CTRL+SHIFT+A` and type "**pull**". Click on the first option. From the menu, select **both** branches as the origin of the pull. Click ok.

Now you have both branches merged in this branch Project-Rachel. Simply push that and that's it (`CTRL+SHIFT+K`).

Comment: do I need to do anything like git add to bring in MM-mr2?

Comment: I don't get your question. If you want both branches to be **exactly** similar, repeat the same procedure checking out on the other branch, pulling from both and then pushing. If everything is commited and pushed on MM-mr2, you do not need to do anything more on that branch.

Comment: Here is a picture of my github  http://postimg.org/image/rlywhqmon/  I need to merge MM-mr2 into Project-Rachel

Comment: Well you didn't post your question properly, this seems like you're trying to merge 2 projects, not 2 branches of the **same** project. I do not know how to do that.